# Solving and interpreting growth differential equation $P'=aP(B-P)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $P(t)$ be the size of a population at time t and assume that the
>   growth rate $P'=\frac{dP}{dt}$ depends exculsively on P, that is:
>
> $$\frac{dP}{dt}=g(P)$$ with initial population size $P(0)=P_0$
>
> Solve and discuss the following case ($a>0$,$B>P_0):$
>
> $$\text{Logistic growth:}\space \space \space g(P)=aP(B-P)$$

Here is my attempt:

$$ P'=aP(B-P) \iff P'=aPB-aP^2 \\ \iff \frac{P'}{P^2}=aP^{-1}-a $$

Substitution: $v=P^{-1} \implies -v'=\frac{P'}{P^2}$

$$\implies -v'=aBv-a$$

Solving the hom. equation and applying variation of parameters I get:

$$v=\frac{1}{B}+c_1e^{-aBt}$$

Resubstituion:

$$\frac{1}{P}=\frac{1}{B}+c_1e^{-aBt} \iff P= \frac{e^{aBt+c_1B}}{Be^{aBt}}$$

Initial condition: $P(0)=P_0 \implies c_1= \frac{B-P_0}{P_0 B}$

$$\boxed{\implies P(t)=\frac{e^{aBt}+\frac{B-p_0}{P_0}}{Be^{aBt}}}$$

Is this correct? How can I interpret this result? For very large $t$ doesn't this tend to $1$?

Comment: You can also use separation, $aB=\frac{(B-P+P)P'}{P(B-P)}=\frac{P'}{B-P}+\frac{P'}{P}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{P}=\frac{1}{B}+c_1e^{-aBt} \iff P(t)= \frac{B}{1+c_1Be^{-aBt}}$$

so $\lim _{t \to \infty}P(t)=B   $

Which makes sense because $P'=0$ when $P=B$

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me how you got to $P(t)=\frac{B}{1+c_1Be^{-aBt}}$. I keep getting a different result i.e the one I posted in my question.

Comment: @bluemoon $$\frac{1}{P}=\frac{1}{B}+c_1e^{-aBt}=\frac{1}{B}+\frac{c_1Be^{-aBt}}{B}=\frac{1+c_1Be^{-aBt}}{B}$$ Now take recipricals

Comment: My god I am stupid. It looks so easy now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your result is not correct.

Notice, $$\frac{dP}{dt}=aP(B-P)\implies \frac{dP}{P(B-P)}=a\ dt$$
$$\frac{1}{B}\left(\frac{1}{B-P}+\frac{1}{P}\right)dP=a\ dt$$
$$\int \left(\frac{1}{B-P}+\frac{1}{P}\right)dP=aB\int dt$$
$$\ln |P|-\ln|B-P|=aBt+c_1$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{P}{B-P}\right|=aBt+c_1$$
substituting $t=0$ & $P=P_0$, we get $c_1=\ln\left|\frac{P_0}{B-P_0}\right|$
hence, we get $$\ln\left|\frac{P}{B-P}\right|=aBt+\ln\left|\frac{P_0}{B-P_0}\right|$$ 
$$\ln\left|\frac{P(B-P_0)}{P_0(B-P)}\right|=aBt$$
$$P=\frac{P_0Be^{aBt}}{(B-P_0)+P_0e^{aBt}}$$

Comment: However, the approach to treat it as a Bernoulli ODE is one of the correct variants.

Comment: Thanks!

I first solved the hom. eq.:$$v'=-aBv \iff v=ce^{-aBt}$$

then I used "variation of parameters". Setting $v=c(t)e^{-aBt}$

$$\implies c(t)=\int ae^{aBt}=\frac{1}{B}e^{aBt}+c \\ \implies v=(\frac{1}{B}e^{aBt}+c ))e^{-aBt}=\frac{1}{B}+ce^{-aBt}$$

I don't see my error. Can you maybe see it?

Comment: Up to that point there is no error. For the error in the remainder, see the accepted answer of WW1.